# Is there a way to auto add gradient to images?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

Here is my code:

```html
<div class='my-posts-container' id='<%=postobj._id%>'>
        <%var menuid='menu'+postobj._id%>
        <%var imagesource='../'+postobj.blob.path%>
        <div class="my-posts-container-header">
             <%-include('postheader.ejs',{friend:postobj.username,postid:postobj._id});%> 
        </div>
        <div class="menu hide" id="<%=menuid%>" >
            <ul >
                <li><button onclick="viewpost('<%=postobj._id%>')"  >view</button></li>
                <li><button onclick="removepost('<%=postobj._id%>')"  >remove</button></li>
                <!-- <li><button onclick="copypostlink('<%=postobj._id%>')"  >copy link</button></li>
                <li><button onclick="editthispost('<%=postobj._id%>')"  >edit</button></li> -->
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="post-image" >
            
                <img src="<%=imagesource%>" alt="image" height="400px" width="400px" style="margin: 5px;object-fit: contain;" ondblclick="like('<%=postobj._id%>')">
    
        </div>
       
        <span>
            <%-include('likecommentsharesave.ejs',{postid:postobj._id,username:username,likes:postobj.likes})%>
        </span>
        <hr>
        <div class="caption"> 
            <%=postobj.caption%> 
        </div>
```

I want to keep my image size as 400px *400px
but add a background colour .post_image div,
basically, I want to add a gradient to the background based on any image in the image tag, something like this,

[image]

so that the whole 400 X 400  size is covered is this possible to achieve, if not can you suggest me other options, Thanks.

Comment: It seems watermark not just gradient

Comment: what actually looks to me is the same image but with lowered opacity

Comment: What would be the purpose of "gradient" there?

Comment: graidient was just one of the ways acc to me to achive this effect,but now i think this is not possible

Comment: I think to use highly enlarged version of the same image (like above) would be the best way to achieve it. Transparent colors and gradients not going to help here.

Comment: Have a funny feeling your 'automatic gradient' is a [blurred version of your main image](https://jsfiddle.net/7eth54mb/1/) in the background

Comment: Yes it looks like ,as you said, can I have the same image in background but with reduced opacity or a blurred version,,then how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The effect you describe can actually be achieved. You just need to stack the same image with a smaller size on top of the image. The image underneath can then be blurred out and it will span the remainder of the `400px x 400px` area.

To do this, you need to set the `position` field of the enclosing `div` to `relative` and that of both the images to `absolute`. I have reduced the height of the image sitting on top to `200px` and kept the image width the same as the image underneath to resemble the style of the image in the question. Use `filter: blur()` to blur out the larger image.
Blurring softens the edges of the image (Remove the `clip` property and you'll know). Use the `clip` property to make the edges look "crisp".

I have used [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1ELT.jpg) image.
Run the code snippet below to see it in action:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
*{box-sizing: border-box;}
.container {
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
}
.outer {
    filter: blur(5px);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    clip: rect(0,400px,400px,0);
    
}
.inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px; 
}
</style>
<div class="container">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1ELT.jpg" class="outer" height="400px" width="400px">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1ELT.jpg" class="inner" height="200px" width="400px">
</div>
</html>
```

This answers part of your question. Now, to automate the image placement as per size, you can retrieve and update the image dimensions using JavaScript:

```
var image = new Image();

image.onload = function() {
  var height = image.height;
  var width = image.width;

}

image.src = "<source>";
```

The image underneath will always be `400 x 400 px`, you can update the attributes of the image on the top as per its actual retrieved dimensions if it is smaller than `400 x 400 px`. Otherwise, squash it down to `400 x 400 px` to cover the entire image underneath.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve something similar with CSS

Considering using this stylesheet

```
<style type="text/css">
  .blured {
    width:320px;
    height:320px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .blured .blur {
    height:70px;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    filter: blur(7px);
  }

  .blured .top {
    top:0px;
    background: linear-gradient(#000000d9, #00000000)
  }

  .blured .bottom {
    bottom:0px;
    background: linear-gradient(#00000000, #000000d9)
  }
</style>
```

Then use the following markup

```
<div class='blured' style='background-image:url("http://placekitten.com/320/320")'>
  <div class='blur top'></div>
  <div class='blur bottom'></div>
</div>
```

The result will be something like this:

[image]

You can experiment with `linear-gradient` colors and the value for `blur()` to achieve an output close to your requirement.

References:

- [filter:blur()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/blur)
- [background: linear-gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient)